# License error with Saiku Analytics Plugin on Pentaho 6 CE

Tags: pentaho, saiku

I installed Saiku Analytics 3.8.7 on pentaho 6 CE using marketplace with COMMUNITY license, but when i try to use it show me: "Error creating session: License for wrong version please update your free license".

I try create different types of licenses in meteorite.bi with no luck. Also if I want to uninstall it using the marketplace throw me an error.

What I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. 
Saiku Analytics was not working and failed to uninstall without any error in catalina.out and pentaho.log.

To uninstalled plugin I had to call biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/marketplace/processes/**uninstall_plugin.kjb** kettle job. 
It has 3 params:

- *samplesDir* - set it to empty string.
- *uninstallBackup* - (absolute path to folder where plugin backup will be stored) ex: /Users/taras/programs/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/plugin-cache/backups/saiku_backup.
- *uninstallLocation* - (absolute path to folder where plugin is located) ex : /Users/taras/programs/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/plugins/saiku .

Job can be executed using Spoon.

After it I've restarted PUC and installed plugin one more time. I selected plugin version **'3.8.8 (PENTAHO6)'** version from dropdown. Then I followed instructions from popup and downloaded *saiku-olap-util-3.7-SNAPSHOT.jar* to tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/lib/ folder and generated licence on licensing.meteorite.bi (License Type: COMMUNITY_EDITION) and downloaded it into /Users/taras/programs/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/plugins/saiku folder. After PUC restart saiku started to work.

Actually I'm disappointed - PUC 6 is so unstable...not sure if its a good production ready solution :(

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. Turns out in the pentaho marketplace, I had wrongly downloaded the Enterprise version of the plugin, and not the Community edition (they're both under Saiku Analytics plugin entry, but there's a dropdown once you select the plugin that lets you choose the right version).

Comment: This was my case, I just installed the Community version and the problem was solved!

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the appendix of the license data you got. 
When your license looks like **license_localhost.lic** you need to rename it to **license.lic**.

And save to the right location like that: ..\pentaho-solutions\system\saiku

Answer (score 1):

Copy the license file into following path: `./tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/lib/license.lic`

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this Issue
Just try to download Saiku 3.8.8(STABLE) from Marketplace & you can able to apply license for 20 users also..